# Value in Directive is undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a value in Directive which is passed by model.It prints value in controller but in directive it's undefined.
Attaching code snippets,Please update where it is wrong.
Thanks a lot !!

A) **Date & Time input type in MODEL** -

// DATE-PICKER

```
<div class="todo-details-inline">
    <span class="todo-header">Due date</span>
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="vm.task.end_date" 
           top="45" name="endDate" 
           class="nc-input" 
           pickadate-picker date-input-format>
</div>
```

// TIME-PICKER

```
<div style="margin-left:10%;" class="todo-details-inline">
    <input ng-model="vm.task.end_time" 
           name="endTime" 
           time-input-format 
           time-picker 
           taskEndDate="vm.endDate" 
           placeholder="End Time" 
           class="nc-input">
</div>
```

B) **vm.endDate set in controller**

// on page load

```
vm.endDate = vm.task.end_date;
logger.info('in activate,vm.endDate:'+vm.endDate); // prints correct value
```

// watch - on val update

```
vm.endDate = vm.task.end_date;
console.log("updated vm.endDate:"+vm.endDate);   // prints correct value
```

c)  **IN DIRECTIVE**

```
angular
.module('app.layout')
.directive('timePicker', timePicker);

function timePicker($timeout) {
    var directive = {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            from: '=',
            to: '@',
            format: '@',
            min: '=',
            initialTime: '=',
            selectTime: '=',
            taskEndDate:'='
        },
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
          // OTHER CODE     

          $scope.$watch("taskEndDate", function(value) {
            console.log("taskEndDate value:"+value); // UNDEFINED ??
            if (value) {
                // FURTHER OPRTNs
            }
          }
        }
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a local copy of `taskEndValue` before watching it... Some times you watch the passed value before it actually gets value.

```
$scope.endDate = $scope.taskEndDate;
$scope.$watch("endDate", function(value) {
    console.log("taskEndDate value:"+value);
    if (value) {
           ....
   }
});
```

Then watch the local variable in your link.

And secondly your `taskEndDate` in your input tag is case-senstive, which is wrong.

```
<input ng-model="vm.task.end_time" 
           name="endTime" 
           time-input-format 
           time-picker 
           task-end-date="vm.endDate" 
           placeholder="End Time" 
           class="nc-input">
```

Comment: Thanks Thalaivar :) Main Problem was  taskEndDate in input tag,correcting to task-end-date worked